# Accessing absolute file paths from linux kernel driver in the context of application calling from a chroot

Tags: module, path, kernel, absolute, chroot

Linux Driver question.
I have an application effectively calling into my kernel module.
The kernel module has to read files from a specific absolute path, during the call from the application.

This all works fine under normal conditions.

The problem occurs when the application is being run from a chroot.
At that point, running within the context of the application that is running from chroot, my driver no longer has access to the absolute path for the file it must read.

The driver is using filp_open() to open the file, which fails when application is running from chroot.

Is there way for me to specify the root for my file opens to use without disturbing the application's chroot, or causing races with the application accessing other files within the chroot.

The Linux version is centos 7.1 kernel 3.10.0-229-el7.x86_64
Any info greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This took a lot of crawling around through the kernel code, but I figured out how to this.

First I needed to use get_fs_root(init_task.fs, &realrootpath)
This gets the real root path, not the chroot path.

Then I needed to lookup the file name using filename_lookup() setting namei data to my rootpath and passing in the LOOKUP_ROOT flag so it looks it up from the real root path.

Finally I had to use dentry_open() to open the file using the path I looked up.
At this point I could access and read a file that outside the current tasks chroot environment.